# How to get values when returned firebase url for specific item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am querying my firebase using the following, but can't seem to access the `key` `value` pairs under each firebase reference. How can I get those values:

```
//PLEASE NOTE that snap.val().key is a key for another database (in this example -KjexampleZoe5-1exampleJp2UY) 
var desiredItem = this.goodsData.findGoodById(snap.val().key);
// => https://example-url.firebaseio.com/exampleList/-KjexampleZoe5-1exampleJp2UY

//find good by id
findGoodById(goodId): firebase.database.Reference {
    return this.exampleList.child(goodId);
}
```

But when I try to get values using `desiredItem.val().key2` or `desiredItem.key2` I get `Property 'key2' does not exist on type 'Reference'` or `Property 'val' does not exist on type 'Reference'`:

```
-KjexampleZoe5-1exampleJp2UY
  |
  |
  - key: "value"
  |
  |
  - key2: "value2"
  |
  | 
  - key3: "value3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
return firebase.database().ref('/myRef/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      var obj = snapshot.val(); // should be complete object;
      var keyValue = snapshot.val().key //should be object property value
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to use the new 3.1 firebase sdk with

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js'></script>
```

Then you should initialize your app using

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

You will be able to get your config details by going to the console, clicking in your application name and pressing Add Firebase to your Web app.

Then to get your ref object you will need the code bellow.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();
```

Then you can write something like

```
ref.orderByChild("userkey").equalTo("11112").once("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```